# If $M_i$ is a submanifold with $M_1\subseteq M_2$, what's the pushforward of the restriction $\left.f\right|_{M_1}$ of a map $f:M_2\to\mathbb R$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, tangent-spaces, pushforward

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $k_i\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, $M_i$ be a $k_i$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary and $f_i:M_i\to\mathbb R$.

> Assume $M_1\subseteq M_2$ and $f_1=\left.f_2\right|_{M_1}$. I've read that if $f_2$ is $C^1$-differentiable, then $f_1$ is $C^1$-differentiable and $${\rm D}f_1(x_1)=\left.{\rm D}f_2(x_1)\right|_{T_{x_1}\:M_1}\;\;\;\text{for all }x_1\in M_1\tag1.$$

I wondered how trivial this claim actually is. Am I missing something or doesn't $M_1\subseteq M_2$ immediately yield $$T_{x_1}\:M_1=T_{x_1}\:M_2\tag2$$ for all $x_1\in M_1$? What's confusing me is that if $(2)$ is actually true, the restriction on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is not actually a restriction (since by the very definition of the pushforward ${\rm D}f_2(x_1)$ of $f_2$ at $x_1$ this is a map defined on T_{x_1}:M_2$).

BTW, unless $M_1=\emptyset$, am I missing something or doesn't $M_1\subseteq M_2$ necessarily imply that we need to have $k_1=k_2$?

Comment: Only when $M_1$ is an open subset of $M_2$!!!

Comment: @TedShifrin You mean $(2)$ holds only when $M_1$ is $M_2$-open or do you mean that even $(1)$ only holds when $M_1$ is $M_2$-open?

Comment: @TedShifrin I see, "$\supseteq$" in $(2)$ only holds if $M_1$ is $M_2$-open.

Comment: Who says $f(M)$ is even a submanifold? Are you assuming $f$ is an immersion?

Comment: @TedShifrin Forget what I wrote; it didn't make sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was trying to consider the following: If $\nu_{\partial M}$ is the outward pointing unit normal field on the boundary of a $k$-dimensional submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, then we may treat $\nu_{\partial M}$ as a map with values in the unit $(d-1)$-sphere $S^{d-1}$. Now, the pushforward $T_x(\nu_{\partial M})$ maps to $T_{\nu_{\partial M}(x)}S^{d-1}=(\mathbb R\nu_{\partial M}(x))^\perp\supseteq(N_x\partial M)^\perp=T_x\:\partial M$, where $x\in\partial M$. And I was wondering if equality only holds in the case $k=d$,

Comment: @TedShifrin since only in that case $\mathbb R\nu_{\partial M}(x)=N_x\:\partial M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throughout, let $i:M_1\to M_2$ be the inclusion map.

By definition, $f_1=f_2|_{M_1}=f_2\circ i$. Thus, if $i$ is differentiable, then we just have $Df_1(x_1)=Df_2(i(x_1))\circ Di(x_1)=Df_2|_{T_{x_1}M_1}$ by the chain rule. Since we assume $M_1$ and $M_2$ are embedded $C^1$-submanifolds, the fact that the embedding $i$ is differentiable is all but tautological.

As for $M_1\subseteq M_2$ implying $T_{x_1}M_1=T_{x_1}M_2$? No.

Try, for example, $M_2=S^2$ under the standard embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $M_1=S^1$ as a great circle in $S^2$. The 1-dimensional tangent space to $M_1$ is, then, clearly not equal to the 2-dimensional tangent space to $M_2$. What is true is that $T_{x_1}M_1=Di(x_1)(T_{x_1}M_1)\subseteq T_{x_1}M_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $T_{x_1}M_1=T_{x_1}M_2$ should hold if $M_1$ is $M_2$-open. Do you agree?

Comment: And regarding the differentiability of $i$: We know that if $f$ is a function on $M$ is $C^1$-differentiable at $x\in M$, then $T_x(f)v={\rm D}\tilde f(x)v$ for all $v\in T_x\:M$, where $\tilde f$ is any $C^1$-extension of $f$ at $x$. Now $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}$ is clearly a $C^\infty$-extension of $i$. So, we should be able to conclude that $i$ is $C^\infty$-differentiable and $T_x(i)v=v$ for all $v\in T_x\:M$. But maybe I'm missing something and $i$ is only $C^\alpha$-differentiable (assuming $M$ is a $C^\alpha$-submanifold with boundary).

Comment: Yes, it makes no sense to say a function is $C^k$ on a $C^\alpha$ manifold when $\alpha<k$. You have to work in charts, and so the composition of a $C^\alpha$ function and a $C^k$ function is only $C^{\min(\alpha,k)}$